# Google Calendar API Time

Tags: php, laravel, google-calendar-api

When I try to format `2015-05-29T19:30:00+08:00` from google calendar api;

```
return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(
        strtotime('2015-05-29T19:30:00+08:00')
        );
```

I get the result `2015-05-29 11:30:00`
But the start date of the event in my google calendar is exactly `07:30PM`
One thing is that if I try to add a `->diffForHumans();` I get the result:

`16 minutes ago` **(Note: the time I run the code is 7:46PM)**

Can you help me to understand what is going on in here.

Comment: Looks completely correct, read a bit more about Time Zones (apparently you are in a +8hrs timezone, and the function returns UTC)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I already added `->timezone('Timezone/Sample')` and I already get the correct result. Thank you again @Bokw

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the datetime to a unix timestamp, try directly creating a DateTime instance using the original date format which is ISO8601, this should automatically take into account the timezone

```
return Carbon::createFromFormat(Carbon::ISO8601, '2015-05-29T19:30:00+08:00');
```